# Python wrapper not working: swig_import_helper() error

Tags: python, swig, imebra

This is related to [Reading Dicom files in Dlang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56278268/reading-dicom-files-in-dlang)

I am trying Python wrapper for Imebra as shown in above post.

Python_wrapper.so is created by following command:

```
$ g++ -shared -o python_wrapper.so -fPIC -I../../library/include/ -I/usr/include/python3.5m -L../../build -limebra python_wrapper.cxx
```

I try to load it with following simple python file:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../../build')
from imebra import *            # does not work;  
# import imebra                 # also does not work;
```

But I get following error:

```
$ python3 rnImebra.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "..../0-Imebra-dicom/wrappers/pythonWrapper/imebra.py", line 14, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named '_imebra'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rnImebra.py", line 5, in <module>
    import imebra                               #  also does not work; 
  File "..../0-Imebra-dicom/wrappers/pythonWrapper/imebra.py", line 17, in <module>
    _imebra = swig_import_helper()
  File "..../0-Imebra-dicom/wrappers/pythonWrapper/imebra.py", line 16, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_imebra')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_imebra'
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved?

Comment: Where is *python\_wrapper.so* supposed to be used?

Comment: I am looking for explanation and answer.

Answer (score 1):

After downloading the source distribution, just install the python library as explained in the [user manual](https://imebra.com/wp-content/uploads/documentation/4.5/html/compiling_imebra.html#compiling-the-python-version-of-imebra).

```
cd imebra
python setup.py install
```

or

```
cd imebra
python setup.py install --user
```

Comment: This is much simpler as compared with installing for golang or for java. I want to understand how to use swig-generated wrapper file. Can you explain that process for python?

Comment: The Python setup tools provide facilities to compile also the C++ part of the library, so the setup.py script contains the necessary instructions to compile the library and its C++ wrappers into a single dynamic library and installs everything (compiled library + python wrappers) in the correct location

Comment: Basically, SWIG generates a wrapper in the destination language (e.g. in Java, Python, etc) and one in C++, which performs the conversion between the destination language and C++ (e.g. for Java it uses JNI). The C++ generated file can be compiled on its own (uses the Imebra library as dependency) or together with the library (e.g. as the setup.py python script does).